# Ajax call caching CSS - IE7

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I am trying to fix a few styling bugs in IE7 (surprise). Right now, I have a jquery ajax call pulling in content from another page, much like an iFrame. This content is displayed in a jQuery dialog box.

I cannot make these modification because IE7 is caching this css pretty deeply. Yes, I have cleared the browser cache and have added cache: false to the ajax call properties. I even tried adding an irrelevant date() and getTime() variable to the url.

```
function getDocAlert() {
var currentLoc = document.domain;

if ((currentLoc == "stuff.com") || (currentLoc == "junk.com")) {
    loadPreview("derp/alerts.html");
} else {
    loadPreview("herp/alerts.html");
}
$(".preview-link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
};

function loadPreview(url) { 

url = url + '?cache' + new Date().getTime();

var dialog = $('<div style="display:none" class="loading"></div>').appendTo('body');
// open the dialog
dialog.dialog({
    width: 850,
    height: 600,
    position: top,
    // add a close listener to prevent adding multiple divs to the document
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // remove div with all data and events
        dialog.remove();
    },

    modal: true,
        buttons: {Close: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close");
    }}
});

var content = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    context: document.body,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.loading').html(data);
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: If you go directly to the URL in your browser and then hard refresh the page does the content actually change?

Comment: Yeah, I can go directly to the URL and make style changes. They will update with a simple refresh. The only thing hindering me from making style changes directly from the URL is because the jQuery dialog box is causing the IE7 issues. Also, the content inside the dialog box uses stylesheets on both pages.